Create Foreign Key and Primary key Connections with SQLALCHEMY in Python & Pandas
Alright, I am going to modify this post to make sure that I am giving all of the useful information. So I am working on creating a database in MySQL using pandas and sqlalchemy. I have an Excel file that contains various sheets and columns with different information that I am processing using python and adding into a MySQL database I have predesigned using the workbench (not sure if I should try to engineer the connections using python itself, but I found this easier to start with, and am attempting to add data to the table).
This is an example of the database EER structure thus far:
EER diagram of my database
Basically, I have 5 parts of my database currently:

a table for category types,
a table connecting these category types to patient numbers,
a table establishing patient numbers with demographic information and connecting to an index for slides,
a table connecting the index for slides to accession numbers, and
a table connecting accession numbers to slide annotations.

My foreign key constraints therefore are slide_category (for category types referencing the data category table), patient numbers referencing the patient_info table (which are supposed to be auto incremented), patient_slide_id referencing the patient_info table (also auto incremented), and accession no referencing the patient_slides table.
There are two slide categories that have to pair up with each patient number, or a patient can reside in two different slide categories. In addition, a patient can have multiple patient_slide ids.
My first question is, does the format of the EER diagram make sense?
Secondly, when adding data with pandas.to_sql how can I establish the necessary connections for the foreign key columns and create the required unique constraints to be able to drop this data in? Or would this need to be done separately one by one using sqlalchemy?

As slide_category is 2-3 letters, make slide_category a VARCHAR(3) in both the patient_info and data_category table.
Before adding the FK constraint:
ALTER TABLE patient_info MODIFY slide_category VARCHAR(3)
ALTER TABLE data_category MODIFY slide_category VARCHAR(3)


So, I edited my previous post to give this explanation as well, but I am using a pandas dataframe with the method to translate the data from an excel file into mySQL as I am more familiar with python. I am not sure how to establish a VARCHAR(3) in the pandas dataframe or the method to follow your suggestion. This is also a problem when I try with another portion of my code that has a BLOB/TEXT region as an accession number for data and try to link that to another table. Is there maybe a more direct way using pandas to create foreign and primary keys?

Maybe there is a way to add data to tables that I have already created foreign and primary key columns in mysql workbench? When I tried this method before it kept giving me 3730 Operational Errors for key constraint failures even though I made sure that I had columsn with the same name in my pandas dataframe and the same general format. Could this also have been because of VARCHAR variable settings?

I don't know enough about pandas to answer that. Hopefully someone else does. The cause if FK constraints aren't easy to implement when you have BLOB/TEXT as the data type (as its defined as up to 64k in length). This is why the error is insisting of a more minimal length (under ~3k from my memory)
